# pasar datos de un webview a una caja de texto en un activity en android se puede

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, activity, webview

buenas tardes grupos disculpen las molestias
alguien que pudiera orientarme de como pasar datos de un webview a una caja de texto que tengo en una activity
osea lo que quiero es poder seleccionar uno de esos elementos de la lista consultados desde un webview y pasar ese valor a la caja de texto en una activity se podrá
gracias de antemano

Comment: Se recomienda agregar lo que trataste.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que puedes intentar lo siguiente:

Según la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) de `webview` primero debería crear un `JavascriptInterface` y agregarlo cuando haces el setup de tu webview. Como estas tratando con java script, tienes que habilitarlo también.

```
/** Instantiate the interface and set the context  */
class WebAppInterface(private val mContext: Context) {

    /** Show a toast from the web page  */
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun showToast(toast: String) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true        
webView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this), "Android")
```

Luego desde el lado de javascript. Tendrían que mandar algo como esto.

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

Espero te ayude :)